# Do we need the rule "checking duplicate keys" in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eslint

This example is coppied from [disallow duplicate keys in object literals (no-dupe-keys)](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-dupe-keys):

```
var foo = {
    bar: "baz",
    bar: "qux"
};
```

When we call it:

```
alert(foo['bar']);
```

The string `qux` would be thrown. That also means, `foo['bar'] = "baz"` had been overriden, and it couldn't be assigned to. So, you should remove it.

Is it good?

I will take another example:

```
let element = $('<span/>').text('Hi!');
element.css({
    display: '-webkit-box',
    display: '-moz-box'
});
```

Well, `display: '-webkit-box'` would be overriden and couldn't be assigned, too?

No, it's useful on Chrome, `-moz-box` would be used on FF. So, they are different.

Then, the rule is breaking...

Should it be edited for future?

Comment: your second example would always use the -moz-box display property, never the first. ***even in chrome.*** There's no case where not having this rule would be more useful than having it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we do [need this rule].

Re-assigning a value in an object is at best useless and misleading, at worst it's an outright bug.

Your second example is still a plain old JS object and you're overwriting `display`.